# Made a small php script , need to test it but it doesn't outpost anything by default. How do I make it output?

Tags: php, xml, variables

I tried putting echo $steamrep_id but no luck , can anyone help? Code:

```
<?php
class Steam_Rep_Rep {

    // cURL Variable
    private $ch = null;

    public function __construct() {
        // Setup cURL
        $this->ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
    }    

    public function getUserInfo($steamrep_id) {
        // cURL
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://steamrep.com/api/beta/reputation/{$steamrep_id}?json=1");
        $result = curl_exec($this->ch);
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);

        if(!empty($xml)) {
            return array(
                'rep' => $xml->steamREP,

            );
        } else {
            return array(
                'rep' => "No reputation found",
            );
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Basically , it takes data from the XML file and stores it in the variable.
Also note I'm a semi-newbie to coding , I just took parts of other codes and stuck it together to make this work , I'm not even sure it does it's job.
EDIT: No I won't execute the variable , I will just make a code which takes the data from the variable and thats it.

Comment: Are you actually executing the code? Do you have `new Steam_Rep_Rep` anywhere?

Comment: If you are a newbie, start with newbie stuff, not XML parsing and cURL calls. Get to know programming and PHP basics first. Lots of resources are to be found online.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$test = new Steam_Rep_Rep();

$var = $test->getUserInfo("id_goes_here");

var_dump($var);
```

Put this at the end of your script and then run it in the browser.

Comment: If I replace id_goes_here it says : array(1) { ["rep"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (0) { } }  but if I use the id_oes_here it just says array(1) { ["rep"]=> string(19) "No reputation found" }

Comment: I need it to take the data from the XML file , not show the above :\

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors, replace `STEAM_ID64` with STEAM_ID and it should work

```
class Steam_Rep_Rep {

    // cURL Variable
    private $ch = null;

    public function __construct() {
        // Setup cURL
        $this->ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
    }    

    public function getUserInfo($steamrep_id) {
        // cURL
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://steamrep.com/api/beta/reputation/{$steamrep_id}?json=1");
        $result = curl_exec($this->ch);
        $xml = json_decode($result);
        if(!empty($xml->steamrep->reputation)) {
            return array(
                'rep' => $xml->steamrep->reputation,
            );
        } else {
            return array(
                'rep' => "No reputation found",
            );
        }
    }
}

$steam = new Steam_Rep_Rep();
$rep = $steam->getUserInfo('76561197971691194');
echo $rep['rep'];
```

Comment: Now instead of just taking the data from the XML , it just does this: array(1) { ["rep"]=> string(32) "SR DONATOR,REDDIT ADMIN,SR ADMIN" } If I will make something that takes the data from the variable , will it take out the SR DONATOR and so on?

Comment: Yes .. it means that user has 3 titles in reputation and you can explode those by `,` like: `$all = explode(',', $rep);`

Comment: Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\Users\Arcaneex\Documents\NuSphere PhpED\Projects\noname2.php on line 37  This is what I get now :(

Comment: 76561197971691194  Basically , I just need to have 2 variables , which if called ( like read the variables ) it will outpost either the Scammer status either the Caution status.

Comment: modified .. check now (added `echo $rep['rep'];`)